# show the Wronskian is constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let $p,q : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R^n}$ and $H:\Bbb{R^n}\times \Bbb{R^n} \to \Bbb{R} $

and the hamiltonian system:

$$ \begin{cases} 
\dot p = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} \\
\dot q =  \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} 
\end{cases} $$

1. show that for p,q solutions of the system $ H(p,q)$ is constant over time
2. show that given that the system is linear then it's Wronskian is constant

I solved 1 by simply deriving $H(p,q)$ and getting that it's 0

for 2, I think that by using the formula $$ w(t) = w(t_0) e^{\int trA(s)ds} $$ 
I need to show that $tr(A )= 0$, but cant I manage to show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear means that $H(p,q)$ is a quadratic form $H(p,q)= <Sp,p>+2<Tp,q>+  <Uq,q>$, $S,U$ symmetric.Then the matrix $A$ is the bloc matrix $ (-2T, -2U)$ on the first $n$ lines $(2S, 2T^t)$ on the last $n$ lines. Its trace is $0$, as $tr T=tr T^t$.

Comment: can you please explian why H(p,q) is a quadratic form. and why is that the form of A?

Comment: Let me explain if $n=1$ ${\partial H \over \partial p}= sp+tq, $, You find $H= sp^2/2+tqp+ C(q)$ from the second equation you find $C(q)=uq^2/2+cte$. The general case is obtained by a similar argument

Comment: this something I have thaught about at first, but then seemed wrong because p is a function and not a variable, so wont the deritative be: $\frac {\partial H}{\partial p} = sp\dot p + tq\dot p $

Comment: no just write that $\dot p$ is linear in $p,q$

Comment: sorry, I still dont quit understand so wont I'll get $\frac {\partial H}{\partial p} = sp\dot p + tq\dot p = sp (ap + bq) + tq (ap + bq) \ne sp + tq$

Comment: When you write "the system is linear", what do you mean exactly ? for me this means that $\dot p= ap+bq, \dot q= cp+dq$.

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I mean

Comment: replace $\dot p$ by $\partial H \over \partial q$, and integrate

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you mean to integrate $ \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} = ap + bq $ in order to get $ H= ap^2/2 +tqp + C(q)$, but I dont understand why is that true. p and q are not variables they are function. so if we derive that H we get $ \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} = ap\dot p + tq\dot p \ne ap+bq$